# unable to run npm start in the browser and getting error in win 7

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have just started working with reactjs and for that i have already installed nodejs and in the command i have install the npm install create-react-app and after that i have created create-react-app react-newscard. After the creating it when i tried to run it by using npm start , i was getting the following error as shown in the image.So tell me what i am doing wrong and help me solve the problem and start the code.

[It is the link of the error which is shown](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/unable-to-run-reactjs-in-the-browser/293941)

Comment: Welcome to SO! The text in your image says there is a complete log available. Can you copy / paste the contents and update your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do.

- Check `node -v` (See if it gives you a version)
- Check `npm -v` (See if it gives you a version)

If you're getting all the versions, it means your node installation is fine

Then:

```
npm i -g create-react-app
create-react-app react-newscard --scripts-version 1.1.5
```

(You can skip the part from "--scripts-version 1.1.5")

`npm start` by default runs your code using port 3000. sometimes port 3000 is occupied so one of two things can happen

- Either your terminal will prompt you if the application can be rendered in a different port
- Or It closes without intimation

If it is getting closed without intimation here is what you do
(replace the below in line in package.json > scripts)

```
"start": "set PORT=4200 && react-scripts start",
```

Comment: can you link your project somewhere so we can have a look?